# When trying to upload file, FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed() error occurr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I receive a image file with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile` type in Controller.

And I upload this file on Azure Blob.

Before that I take a process like following

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async void ActionMethod(IFormFile img)
{

    // some process        

    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // (1)
        img.CopyTo(stream); // (2)
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // call await cloud block blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }

    // some process
}
```

When get through `using` the stream is

**stream**

```
CanRead:    true
CanSeek:    true
CanTimeout: false
CanWrite:   true
Capacity:   0
Length:     0
Position:   0
ReadTimeout:  'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout: 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

and at and after point `(2)` the following error occur

```
System.ObjectDisposedException occurred
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object
  ObjectName: 'FileBufferingReadStream'
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
  StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ReferenceReadStream..ctor(Stream inner, Int64 offset, Int64 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile.OpenReadStream()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile.CopyTo(Stream target)
   at AzureStorageManager.AzureStorageFileModules.<UploadFileAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

The real problem is that the obove codes work well some situation but not in some(I can not catch the situation. The `file` is same in every time).

Please help me...

Comment: you can try this code within the `UploadIFormFile` function https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore.azure.blob/blob/master/NetCore.Azure.Blob/BlobManagerExtension.cs

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Thanks ! I will reference it when I do refactoring!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggle to solve this problem for a day and right after upload this question I found a solution. The problem which make this issue is the return type of Action method. If the return type is not `Task<T>` the error is occurred. So I fixed my Action Method like

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<int> ActionMethod(IFormFile img)
{
     // same

     return resultValue;
}
```

After it, the error does not show up.
Actually I don't know why exactlly. So If you know, tell me and share your **knowledge**. Thanks.

Comment: Async void runs your method in the background so your request ends without waiting for it. You should almost never use async void.

Comment: @Tratcher Thank you tell me the reason! I will never use like that :)