# IFormFileCollection: Cannot access a Disposed Object

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, .net-5, filestream

I am trying to upload a document into Azure Blob but it throws an error as below while reading the file stream.

Error,

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'.
```

The error comes when the code OpenReadStream() called,

```
public async Task UploadAsync(IFormFileCollection files, string directoryName)
    {
        var blobContainer = await _azureBlobConnectionFactory.GetBlobContainer();
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blockblob = directory.GetBlockBlobReference(files[i].FileName);
            using (var stream = files[i].OpenReadStream())
            {
                await blockblob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling the UploadAsync method from my actual service classs like,

```
public async Task<bool> UploadToBlob(DocumentModel model,string directorypath)
    {
        try
        {
            //string directory = directorypath + model.EmailId + "/" + model.Files[0].FileName;
            await _blobService.UploadAsync(model.Files, "Documents/dummy.pdf");

           
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Where I did go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The return method of Action method can be a possible reason for this issue
- The error occurs if the return type is not `Task<T>`.
  You can modify your Action Method as follows:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<int> ActionMethod(IFormFile img)
{
     // same

     return resultValue;
}
```

**References :**

1. [When trying to upload file, FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed() error occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054574/when-trying-to-upload-file-filebufferingreadstream-throwifdisposed-error-occu)
2. [Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: FileBufferingReadStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290017/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-object-name-filebufferingreadstream)
3. [IFormFile copy to memorystream ObjectDisposedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654285/iformfile-copy-to-memorystream-objectdisposedexception)

Comment: I missed the key 'async' in the POST enpoints